# How to get sender list from Mandrill API using PHP

Tags: php, api, mandrill

How to get sender list (list of email sent by mandril) through Mandrill PHP api ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you will get all api & its documentation from below link

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.php.html

With the help of this i resolved my issue.

Thanks